# Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts VB.NET MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need to develop Client/Server Application in VB.Net, Database is MySQL.
So, Now I am doing connection testing. I created Connection string and it connected successfully in Server. Its working perfect. My Connection string is

```
Dim myConnectionString As String =
    "SERVER=192.168.2.193;PORT=3306;UID=root;PASSWORD=globe;DATABASE=firstdb;"
```

But When I am trying to access from Client, it shows error : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Please help me to clear this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Either wrong credentials for the database login or wrong ip-port.

Comment: I am using default port number. When I am installed, I could see the port Number. What is credentials for the database?

Comment: Username and password.

Comment: That also right. It working perfect in server only. When I am access from client to server, it shows the error..

Comment: Actually I am using My laptop as server. Is this any problem? When I am access from another laptop, it shows the error.

Comment: Mr.Thanos..... I cleared this issue... Just gave the permission for client and checked firewall in server. Now its working..... Thank you Thonas.                          "mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.1.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"